# В Visual Studio Code в панели PROBLEMS не отображаются ошибки

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Если в проекте открыть файл где есть ошибка, то в ошибка отобразится в PROBLEMS, но если закрыть файл, то ошибка исчезает. Из за чего сложно становится отслеживать ошибки в коде, если файлов в проекте очень много. Есть возможность настроить, чтобы в PROBLEMS отображались все ошибки и предупреждения в проекте?

Comment: Какой это язык?

Comment: Язык TypeScript